# Failed to generate resource table for split ''

Tags: android

I am trying to create an Android application. Currently it won't run and it will give me 2 errors.

[image]

I am unsure on how to get the first error to go away as well as the second one. When I check the console this is what I get.

```
[2015-01-29 16:16:48 - TipCalculator] Failed to generate resource table for split ''
[2015-01-29 16:16:48 - TipCalculator] /Users/lewismenelaws/Documents/workspace/TipCalculator/res/values/dimens.xml:7: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'textview_margin8dp' with value 'textview_margin 8dp').
[2015-01-29 16:16:48 - TipCalculator] 
[2015-01-29 16:17:04 - TipCalculator] Failed to generate resource table for split ''
[2015-01-29 16:17:04 - TipCalculator] /Users/lewismenelaws/Documents/workspace/TipCalculator/res/values/dimens.xml:7: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'textview_margin8dp' with value 'textview_margin 8dp').
[2015-01-29 16:17:04 - TipCalculator] 
[2015-01-29 16:18:05 - TipCalculator] Failed to generate resource table for split ''
[2015-01-29 16:18:05 - TipCalculator] /Users/lewismenelaws/Documents/workspace/TipCalculator/res/values/dimens.xml:7: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'textview_margin8dp' with value 'textview_margin 8dp').
[2015-01-29 16:18:05 - TipCalculator] 
[2015-01-29 16:26:28 - TipCalculator] Failed to generate resource table for split ''
[2015-01-29 16:26:28 - TipCalculator] /Users/lewismenelaws/Documents/workspace/TipCalculator/res/values/dimens.xml:7: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'textview_margin8dp' with value 'textview_margin 8dp').
[2015-01-29 16:26:28 - TipCalculator] 
[2015-01-29 16:26:46 - TipCalculator] Failed to generate resource table for split ''
[2015-01-29 16:26:46 - TipCalculator] /Users/lewismenelaws/Documents/workspace/TipCalculator/res/values/dimens.xml:7: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'textview_margin8dp' with value 'textview_margin 8dp').
[2015-01-29 16:26:46 - TipCalculator] 
[2015-01-29 16:27:49 - TipCalculator] Failed to generate resource table for split ''
[2015-01-29 16:27:49 - TipCalculator] /Users/lewismenelaws/Documents/workspace/TipCalculator/res/values/dimens.xml:7: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'textview_margin8dp' with value 'textview_margin 8dp').
[2015-01-29 16:27:49 - TipCalculator] 
[2015-01-29 16:28:11 - TipCalculator] Failed to generate resource table for split ''
[2015-01-29 16:28:11 - TipCalculator] /Users/lewismenelaws/Documents/workspace/TipCalculator/res/values/dimens.xml:7: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'textview_margin8dp' with value 'textview_margin 8dp').
[2015-01-29 16:28:11 - TipCalculator] 
[2015-01-29 16:29:32 - TipCalculator] Failed to generate resource table for split ''
[2015-01-29 16:29:32 - TipCalculator] /Users/lewismenelaws/Documents/workspace/TipCalculator/res/values/dimens.xml:7: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'textview_margin8dp' with value 'textview_margin 8dp').
[2015-01-29 16:29:32 - TipCalculator] 
[2015-01-29 16:29:51 - TipCalculator] Failed to generate resource table for split ''
[2015-01-29 16:29:51 - TipCalculator] /Users/lewismenelaws/Documents/workspace/TipCalculator/res/values/dimens.xml:7: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'textview_margin8dp' with value 'textview_margin 8dp').
[2015-01-29 16:29:51 - TipCalculator] 
[2015-01-29 16:29:51 - TipCalculator] Dx 
trouble writing output: already prepared
```

I am unsure on what this means and can not find a valid solution on why this is happening. I tried to Clean/Rebuild and that still hasn't help. Thank you.

Here is the dimens.xml file:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="textview_padding">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="textview_margin8dp">textview_margin 8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="textview_margin">8db</dimen>

</resources>
```

Comment: @user3956566 Here is the dimens.xml file. I just posted it to my main post.

Comment: `String types not allowed (at 'textview_margin8dp' with value 'textview_margin 8dp')`  what else can you possibly need?

Comment: @njzk2 I am not familiar with Eclipse. I am asking a question because I don't understand.

Comment: it says you are declaring a thing that is named `textview_margin8dp`, which has a value `textview_margin 8dp`, and that value is a type `String`, which is not allowed. Now, by comparing that value with the ones immediately surrounding it, you should notice a difference in the format. (Also, this has nothing to do with Eclipse.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo, you are using a String value to declare the margin.

> Error: String types not allowed (at 'textview_margin8dp' with value 'textview_margin 8dp')

Here:

```
<dimen name="textview_margin8dp">textview_margin 8dp</dimen>
```

It should be:

```
<dimen name="textview_margin8dp">8dp</dimen>
```

Comment: This fixed the issue on that line. Now it gives me an error on the very next line

/Users/lewismenelaws/Documents/workspace/TipCalculator/res/values/dimens.xml:8: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'textview_margin' with value '8db').

Comment: `8db`. What would you think that does?